# Value of type 'GKEntity' has no member 'componentForClass'. why I can`t find this method in swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3, gameplay-kit

I'm trying to run this line:

```
guard let spriteComponent = entity?.componentForClass(SpriteComponent.self) else {
   return
}
```

and receiving this:

> Value of type 'GKEntity' has no member 'componentForClass'

Apparently apple has removed this method from `GamePlayKit` `GkEntity` class. So which method should I use instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift 3 this has changed to [`component(ofType:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/gameplaykit/gkentity/2300466-component). So your expression will look like;

```
guard let spriteComponent = entity?.component(ofType: SpriteComponent.self) else {
   return
}
```